# Capturing URL params in Django Rest

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to capture the url params in the following url 
"/portal/{pk}/portalProject/{pk}"

the following url is not leading to the view function below . What is wrong here?

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movies', MoviesViewSet)
router.register(r'project', ClientViewSet)
router.register(r'portal', PortalViewSet)
router.register(r'portal/(?P<portal_pk>\d+)/portalProject/(?P<portalProject_pk>\d+)/$', PortalViewSet, 'portalProject')
router.register(r'portalProject', PortalProjectViewSet)
```

views.py

```
class PortalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @detail_route(methods=['post','get'])
    def portalProject(self, request, pk=None):
        print "in here"
        if request.method == 'post':
            #some code            
            serializer = PortalProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                print "valid"
                serializer.save()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                print serializer.errors
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            #some code
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    ...
```

Comment: just for slow readers like myself: `portalProject` is a method inside a PortalViewSet class (which derives ViewSet).

Comment: I fail to find any example in which `DefaultRouter` accepts a regular expression as first parameter. I assume that you cannot...?

Comment: Yes Default router does not accept Reg EX . I was trying different things . Copied the same here .

Comment: Ok! Just in case I was unaware of some neat feature of `DefaultRouter` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually declare a specific route in [`DefaultRouter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter). The `router` takes care of creating all sub urls for you. Just doing `router.register(r'portal', PortalViewSet)` will give you:

- [.format]
- {prefix}/[.format]
- {prefix}/{methodname}/[.format] - `@list_route` decorated method
- {prefix}/{lookup}/[.format]
- {prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}/[.format] - `@detail_route` decorated method

So unless you want to create a custom router, you're gonna have to change your url pattern to something like `/portal/{pk}/portalProject/?id={pk}`

Also, if you're requesting the `portalProject` by `pk` anyway, then there is no need for nesting the url under `/portal/{pk}`. The `pk` of `portalProject` is already specific enough. You already have a route for `portalProject`, so you would effectively be getting two ways of accessing the same data, one of them being more complicated for no good reason.

However, I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers
or https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes

Comment: Yes this url http://localhost:8000/v1/portal/1/portalProject/?pid=11 works but I am looking at something like http://localhost:8000/v1/portal/1/portalProject/11

Comment: Yes I already have PortalProjectViewSet , I am looking to remove that and provide a kind the url /portal/{id}/portalProject/{id}

Comment: Does that have any practical application?

Comment: Thanks for the links . Is there any other way to do this ? I don't want to install extra package .

Comment: I don't think `django-rest-framework` is designed for this kind of nesting. Obviously this is possible, but it's always going to be much more work than just going with the standard. Here is another approach: https://gist.github.com/kevin-brown/6112838